# Blender - three.js export - Linked Groups

Tags: export, three.js, blender

I have a blender scene containing an Instance of a Linked Group.

When exporting to three.js, the geometry for the elements of that group are not being exported as separate files.

If I **append** (not link) the group to the scene and then select "Embed meshes" when exporting the json files contains all the geometries from the referenced .blender file that stores the group.

However, duplicating the group adds another identical set of meshes doubling the size of the file.

What would be the best practice workflow for this scenario:

- lib.blender - containing a group (like a tree with branches and leaves)
- forest.blender - the scene with several instances of the same tree.
- export from blender to three.js and loading the scene using SceneLoader.